# Trying to make query on condition

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I read most of the solutions here with similar questions and it did not solve my problem and I cannot find anything online that can help me.

I am trying to make query on condition where `user_id = session user_id` but I get error when I make `INNER join`

> ambiguous column name

for this

```
public List<CartModelClass>getCarts1(){

    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

    String[] sqlSelect = { "ID" , "user_id", "food_id", "quantity", "price", "origin", "destination","description","company_name","search_id"};

    String sqltable2 = "OrderDetails LEFT JOIN OrderDetails WHERE user_id LIKE '%%' ";

    qb.setTables(sqltable2);
    Cursor c = qb.query(db,sqlSelect, null, null ,null ,null ,null);

    final List<CartModelClass> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            result.add(new CartModelClass(
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("user_id")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("food_id")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("quantity")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("price")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("origin")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("destination")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("description")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("company_name")),
                    c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("search_id"))
            ));
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    return result;
}
```

so I changed `InnerJoin` and made it just table `where user_id like"%%"` but I only get the last `user_id` who added to cart and show all data for all users

I want to show only added cart for `user_id = session user_id` so i can use it in here

loadListFood

```
private void loadListFood(){


sessionManager= new SessionManager(getActivity());
final Hashmap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
user.get(USER_ID);

listdata = new Database(this.getContext.getCarts1());
for(CartModelClass order : listdata)
user_id = order.getUser_id


if(user.get(USER_ID).equals(user_id)){
listdata = new Database(this.getContext()).getCarts();


        adapter = new CartAdapter(listdata, this.getContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


        int total = 0;
        for (CartModelClass order : listdata) {


            total += (Integer.parseInt(order.getPrice())) * (Integer.parseInt(order.getQuantity()));
            Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US");

            NumberFormat fmt = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
            txtTotalPrice.setText(fmt.format(total));
        }
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No Cart Added", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are self joining the table `OrderDetails`.
In this case you must set aliases to both copies of the table, like:

```
OrderDetails as o1 LEFT JOIN OrderDetails as o2 ...
```

Now in the `ON` clause you must qualify the column names properly, like:

```
ON o1.user_id = o2.something
```

If you don't, you get that error message, because the column name `user_id` could belong to either of the 2 copies of the table. 
Also:
What is `session user_id`? Is it a column name?
If it is then the problem is that it contains a space in its name.
Enclose it in square brackets, so the statemnet should be:

```
OrderDetails as o1 LEFT JOIN OrderDetails as o2
ON o1.user_id = o2.[session user_id]
```

Comment: still same error >ambiguous column name .. session user_id is from Session manager activity where it make session for logged in user

Comment: What is *Session manager activity*? In sql we use column names, not activity widgets

Comment: i know i know nothing about sqlite so i thought i would be the same as Mysql php so im using user_id column as a reference as when i  press CartFragment it uses the IF statement where user_id from the table .equals session user_id from session activity

Comment: and i to works when i delete the Join and make it user_id = '%%' but it only select the last user_id who was added to Cart local database and show all results for all users